# Need to create an array to reveal correct letters

Tags: c#, arrays

Code works the way I want it to. I am having trouble making an array to replace the *s in Console.WriteLine("The word is *******."); .... The array has to reveal the correct letters in their correct place and I am hopelessly lost.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int correctcounter = 0;
            int wrongcounter = 0;
            char l1 = 'j';
            char l2 = 'o';
            char l3 = 'h';
            char l4 = 'n';
            char l5 = 's';
            char[] correctletters = { 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n', 's', 'o', 'n' };
            char[] guessedletters = new char[10];


            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Hangman Game!");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You have 10 tries to guess the word right.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The word is *******.");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Guessed letters: [{0}]", string.Join(",", guessedletters));
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Your total wrong guesses:{0}.", wrongcounter);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    guessedletters[i] = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (guessedletters[i] == l1 || guessedletters[i] == l2 || guessedletters[i] == l3 || guessedletters[i] == l4 || guessedletters[i] == l5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");
                        correctletters[i] = guessedletters[i];
                        correctcounter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("You guessed incorrectly");
                        wrongcounter++;
                    }

                    if (correctcounter == 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("You guessed the word, [{0}]. You WIN!", string.Join("",correctletters));
                        break;
                    }
                    if (wrongcounter == 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("You LOSE! The word was [{0}]. You LOSE!", string.Join("", correctletters));
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please hit enter to end the program");
                    Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See *Console.SetCursorPosition*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's try to do that slowly, with structures you already know of.

So, to achieve our goal, we will work with an other array, which will hold the word to reveal to the user. We'll call it 'wordToReveal':

```
char[] wordToReveal = {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'};
```

When the user finds a correct letter, we will fill it with the correct letters.

If we move to the first `if`, we can see you already tried to alter the correctLetters with the guessedLetters:

```
correctletters[i] = guessedletters[i];
```

However, what this code is doing is wrong. You are using the index `i` (which is the turn #) to change the correct letter to what the user guessed. So if we're at the 3rd turn, the user input 'j', you'll end-up with your correct word looking like this : joh**j**son.

Instead of this, we will loop through your current 'correctLetters' and change the "word to reveal" to show the real letters. To loop, we're using an other `for` loop, with a variable called `j` (because `i` is already taken!). This variable will go from 0 up to the end of the array.

In that loop, we'll check if the letter at the index j have been guessed by the user. If it is the case, we'll overwrite the `*` by the correct letter:

```
for (int j = 0; j < correctletters.Length; j++)
{
    if (guessedletters.Contains(correctletters[j]))
    {
        wordToReveal[j] = correctletters[j];
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to display the word. To do that, we'll replace your string `"The word is *******."` with our new word to reveal :

```
Console.WriteLine("The word is " + string.Concat(wordToReveal) + ".");
```

By the way, `string.Concat` is exactly like the `string.Join` you were using. The difference is that you do not have to specify an empty string as a delimiter, it joins the array together by itself.

The final code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int correctcounter = 0;
            int wrongcounter = 0;
            char l1 = 'j';
            char l2 = 'o';
            char l3 = 'h';
            char l4 = 'n';
            char l5 = 's';
            char[] correctletters = { 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n', 's', 'o', 'n' };
            char[] wordToReveal = {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'};
            char[] guessedletters = new char[10];


            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Hangman Game!");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You have 10 tries to guess the word right.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The word is " + string.Concat(wordToReveal) + ".");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Guessed letters: [{0}]", string.Join(",", guessedletters));
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Your total wrong guesses:{0}.", wrongcounter);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter");
                Console.WriteLine();
                guessedletters[i] = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                if (guessedletters[i] == l1 || guessedletters[i] == l2 || guessedletters[i] == l3 || guessedletters[i] == l4 || guessedletters[i] == l5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");
                    for (int j = 0; j < correctletters.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (guessedletters.Contains(correctletters[j]))
                        {
                            wordToReveal[j] = correctletters[j];
                        }
                    }
                    correctcounter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed incorrectly");
                    wrongcounter++;
                }

                if (correctcounter == 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed the word, [{0}]. You WIN!", string.Concat(correctletters));
                    break;
                }
                if (wrongcounter == 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE! The word was [{0}]. You LOSE!", string.Concat(correctletters));
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please hit enter to end the program");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see we declared the new array with the other, changed the `Console.Write` and added the new loop in the first if.

There's a lot of other ways to achieve it, but I hope this was clear enough for you.

Comment: You were a big help. I like that you took the time to work with my code instead of suggesting a ton of changes that would make all my work a moot point. Also the fact that you took it step by step and explained it to me was extremely helpful. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
var secretWord = "shmurple";  // the secret word
var mask = new String('*', secretWord.Length);  // the mask
```

When revealing a letter:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(mask);  // to be able to alter at index
sb[2] = secretWord[2];
mask = sb.ToString();
```

Example:

```
var secretWord = "shmurple";
var mask = new String('*', secretWord.Length);
var sb = new StringBuilder(mask);
sb[2] = secretWord[2];
mask = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The word is {0}.", mask));  // **m*****
```

This is one way... but there are lots more.  I gave this a one-minute consideration, so you might find a more efficient way.

Alternatively, `secretWord` could be a `char` array, so that you don't have to worry about the whole `StringBuilder` business.  Everything else works the same way.

**EDIT:**

I see your new code....  Just create a mask array (same length as the secret word) and when you're revealing a letter, replace it with the `char` from the correct array:

```
char[] secret = { 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n', 's', 'o', 'n' };
char[] solution = Enumerable.Repeat('*', secret.Length).ToArray(); // mask

solution[2] = secret[2];  // example
Console.WriteLine(solution); // **h****
```

That way, all your indexes match and your life is a lot simpler.  If you need to reveal all matches, just use a loop.